# What is the difference between two $ in Linux script

Tags: linux, shell

What is the difference between variable `$processid ($)` and `Date=$(date +'%m-%d-%y')($)`.
Here we are using two kinds of `$` symbols, please let me know what is the difference of those two `$`.

Comment: As a mnemonic, think of `$(...)` as the expansion (`$`) of a subshell `(...)` rather than a parameter. (It's not perfect, since `${...}` is also just parameter expansion, rather than expansion of a command group `{...}`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
1.Date=$(date +'%m-%d-%y')  -> this $ will execute the command(date +'%m-%d-%y')

2.$processid -> this $ will expand the Processid Variable.

Answer (score 0):

From [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/):

> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion
>   The ‘$’ character introduces parameter expansion, command substitution, or arithmetic expansion. The parameter name or symbol to be expanded may be enclosed in braces, which are optional but serve to protect the variable to be expanded from characters immediately following it which could be interpreted as part of the name.
>   ...
>   The basic form of parameter expansion is ${parameter}. The value of parameter is substituted.

Note, that braces `{` and `}` are optional...

> ...
>   3.5.4 Command Substitution
>   Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the command itself. Command substitution occurs when a command is enclosed as follows:
>   $(command)
>   ....
>     Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

So if:

```
a=1
```

then `$a` and `${a}` expand to `1`.

The following:

```
a=$(echo 2)
```

executes the command `echo` with a single argument `2` in a subshell and grabs it's standard output (`echo 2` will write `2` with a newline on standard output). So it expands to:

```
a=2$'\n'
```

But trailing newlines are removed, so:

```
a=2
```

So `${there:1:2}` `${are:-}` `${many//.*/ways}` `${to##use}` `${the,,}` `${dollar^^$}` `$(( ${!sign} + ${#in} ))` `${!Bash*}`.